# Django - How to authenticate a password with MD5 hash

Tags: python, django, hash, django-forms, django-views

So I'm trying to use the authentication method in my views, but always return "Does not exist", I'm using MD5 hash for my password field, so I don't know if thats the problem

**forms.py**

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    #This Method Hash the password
    def clean_password(self):
        clearPassNoHash = self.cleaned_data['password']
        self.password = md5.new(clearPassNoHash).hexdigest()
        return self.password
```

**views.py**

```
def auth_login(request):
    args = {}
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        print("Exist")
    else:
        print("Does not exist")
```

I've tried with check_password() method(in my forms) that actually works
but I don't know why I'm having trouble with the authenticate()

-----------------------------**UPDATE**--------------------------------

**Views.py**

```
def auth_login(request):
    args = {}
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            print("existe")
            print user
        else:
            print user

    args['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'login/login.html', args)
```

**forms.py**

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

Other observation:
I have this in my settings.py to use my custom model

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'StudentUsers.StudentRegistration'
```

and this is the username field I add to my model:

```
class StudentRegistration(AbstractBaseUser, models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 25, null=False, default="", unique=True)
```

Comment: What is this authenticate method? and does the user really exist? And you really should use form.cleaned_data after checking that form.is_valid()

Comment: authenticate(email=email, password=password), and yes, my user exist

Comment: it's clear from your question that you are calling an authenticate method. My question was what exactly is that authenticate method? where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the email and password from the form's cleaned_data, not from the request directly. Read more on the cleaned_data attribute from the docs : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data

```
password = form.cleaned_data['password']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be hashing the password value yourself. That is what `authenticate` already does; so in effect you are hashing twice.

Comment: Now I've deleted my clean_password method, so I'm passing the plaintext to authenticate, Also, I add an username field in my models so now I'm using my email to authenticate, but It keeps sending me **None**

Comment: You can see my Update, Could it be my Md5hash?

Comment: You probably need to show how you're creating the users in the first place.